# A weakened form of list coloring

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

The list coloring of a simple loopless graph is the assigning of a color from a certain list of colors to every vertex. The list coloring chromatic number of a graph is the minimal cardinality of the list such that the coloring be proper. A graph with list coloring chromatic number $k$ is also said to be $k$ choosable.

Now, consider instead, the following weaker form of list coloring. We assign a color from a list of colors to every indpendent set of vertices, instead of every vertex in the previous case. Then, I think that every graph would be $\chi$ list colorable (in this sense), where $\chi$ be the chromatic number of the graph. This is because, we can always choose a distinct color from any list of distinct $\chi$ elements for a particular indpendent set. Is this the same as normal vertex coloring, or, is this result already studied. Note that the lists may have different elements for each independent set. In this sense, the list edge coloring equals edge coloring. Can this be tacitly used to prove the stronger form of list coloring conjecture(LCC) which states the the chromatic index equals the edge choosability, where the choice is done for each edge separately, instead of independent set? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: why the downvote? Is anything absurd?

Comment: I haven't voted, but you define a new chromatic number, then prove it's equal to the old one.  Why should this help prove the list colouring conjecture but not that chromatic number always equals list chromatic number?  Your new chromatic number was worth thinking about, but it seems you've successfully understood it without help.